# Simple jQuery issue - how to check if $(this) is the last $(this) clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am essentially adding radio-buttons functionality to buttons with the class "tagbutton". There is a flaw with my code, because _this is never _last...

```
  taguid = "";
    _last = "";
    $('.tagbutton').live('click', function() {

    _this = $(this);
    if(_last) {
        //There was a last object
        if(_last == _this) { // The last object was the current object
            alert('deactiveate for this obj');
        } else { // The last object was not the current object
            alert('deactivate last, activate this');
        }
    } else {
        alert('first object activated');
        var taguid = $(this).prev().attr('data-uid');
        alert(taguid);
        _last = $(this);
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the objects' references aren't the same. A simpler way might be to activate the clicked one, then deactivate the last one. It'll have the same effect:

```
var taguid = "";
var _last;
$('.tagbutton').live('click', function() {
if(_last) {
    // There was a last object
    // Activate this
    // Deactivate last
} else {
    alert('first object activated');
    var taguid = $(this).prev().attr('data-uid');
    alert(taguid);
    _last = $(this);
}

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery function `$()` returns a jQuery object, and when you call it a second time you get back a different object.

However, within your event handler the keyword `this` refers to the actual DOM element, so if you save that directly then your comparison should work:

```
_this = this;
// and then later
_last = this;
```